# How to extract a float value from some number(php)

Tags: php

I have a number `1.5`, `1.6666` or `1.777`.

How can I extract those float values from the int part? Not just round but separate them in different vars.

Expected output is `$var1 = 1` and `$var2 = 0.5` for `1.5`.

Comment: Can you give us an example? What output are you expecting from what input?

Comment: Wait, so you want to get each float from a string and _split_ the number? like `1.5` -> `$var1 = '1'` and `$var2 = '5'`?

Comment: $var1 = 1, $var2 = 0.5 like this

Answer (score 1):

First get the integer portion and then subtract it from the original.

```
$original = 1.6666;
$intPortion = intval($original);
$floatPortion = $original - $intPortion;
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. No need to fiddle with the modulus or splitting strings (or, heaven forbid, using a regex here). Just subtract the int from the float.

Comment: @JosephSilber: The way the question is formulated, it's not entirely clear to me if the OP has a single float, or a string (comma-separated) containing multiple floats. In case of the latter, this approach does require a `slit` at the very least

Comment: @JosephSilber: one of them is mine and I asked if OP wants _each float from a string_, which was is still not entirely clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Interpret them as strings, and use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your best bet:

```
$float = 1.666;
$remainder = fmod($float, 1);
$integer = intval($float, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
$var = 1.5;
$arr = explode('.', $var);
$wholeNum = $arr[0];  // 1
$decimalNum = $arr[1];  // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with multiple ways. Lets say `$v = 1.56;` :

**Example #1**

```
$m = explode('.', $v);
$v1 = $m[0];
$v2 = '0.' . $m[1];
print_r("#1: \$v1 = $v1; \$v2 = $v2;\n");
```

**Example #2**

```
preg_match('~^(\d+)\.(\d+)$~', $v, $m);
$v1 = $m[1];
$v2 = '0.' . $m[2];
print_r("#2: \$v1 = $v1; \$v2 = $v2;\n");
```

**Example #3**

```
$v1 = substr($v, 0, strpos($v, '.'));
$v2 = '0.' . substr($v, strpos($v, '.') + 1);
print_r("#3: \$v1 = $v1; \$v2 = $v2;\n");
```

**Example #4**

```
$v1 = floor($v1);
$v2 = $v - $v1;
print_r("#4: \$v1 = $v1; \$v2 = $v2;\n");
```

---

All examples will output >

```
#1: $v1 = 1; $v2 = 0.56;
#2: $v1 = 1; $v2 = 0.56;
#3: $v1 = 1; $v2 = 0.56;
#4: $v1 = 1; $v2 = 0.56;
```

---

Watch out for the big float numbers. See [BC Math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) for those.